# Qt no matching function for call using global variables

Tags: c++, qt

I'm quite new in Qt and C++. I have an issue with global QFile-Variables, that I need in different functions all accros my MainWindow-Class.

```
//mainwindow.h

[...]
public:
    QFile *fIndex;
    QFile *fString;

    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
[...]
```

in the mainwindow.cpp I tried to instantiate:

```
//mainwindow.cpp
[...]
void MainWindow::on_btn_load_load_released() 
{
    QString _index_ = this->ui->txt_load_index->text();
    QString _string_ = this->ui->txt_load_str->text();

    fIndex = new QFile(_index_);
    fString = new QFile(_string_);


    foreach(QString iList, xmlActions::GetXMLID(fIndex))
    {
        this->ui->lst_src_result->addItem(iList);
    }

}
[...]
```

the class, that is called here in the loop contains the following function:

```
//mainheader.h
QList<QString> GetXMLID (QFile XMLIndex)
{
    QList<QString> xList;
    //QFile* xFile = new QFile(XMLFile);

    if (XMLIndex.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QXmlStreamReader reader(XMLIndex.readAll());
        XMLIndex.close();
        while(!reader.atEnd())
        {
            reader.readNext();
            foreach(const QXmlStreamAttribute &attr, reader.attributes())
            {
                if (attr.name().toString() == QLatin1String("ID"))
                {
                   //contList.addItem(attr.value().toString());
                    xList << attr.value().toString();

                }
            }

        }
    }
    return xList;
}
```

somehow the xmlActions::getXMLID(fIndex) doesn't like pointers or something. The compiler complains with:

> no matching function for call to 'xmlActions::GetXMLID(QFile*&)'

I am trying to get this run for donkey's years. I also tried to use the class with constructors and destructors to instantiate. However I can only use it in that single on_btn_load_load_released()-function when I do it like that. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you use `QFile *fIndex;` instead of `QFile fIndex;`?

Answer (score 0):

You use pointer to `QFile`, but your function take `QFile` object as argument. That's why you get this error. If you want use pointer to `QFile`, you need rewrite function with pointer to `QFile` in argument.

Try this:

```
QList<QString> GetXMLID (QFile *XMLIndex)//prototype should be with STAR too
{
    QList<QString> xList;
    //QFile* xFile = new QFile(XMLFile);

    if (XMLIndex->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))//it is a pointer so we should use ->(not .)
    {
    QXmlStreamReader reader(XMLIndex->readAll());
    XMLIndex->close();
    while(!reader.atEnd())
    {
        reader.readNext();
        foreach(const QXmlStreamAttribute &attr, reader.attributes())
        {
            if (attr.name().toString() == QLatin1String("ID"))
            {
               //contList.addItem(attr.value().toString());
                xList << attr.value().toString();

            }
        }

    }
    }
    return xList;
}
```

Or use `QFile fIndex;` instead of `QFile *fIndex;`

After this, error should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

It worked! Thanks a lot. I also had to make the functions static, because i did not make an instance of the class. Using the QFiles not as a pointer did not work somehow, so i made one. Perhaps i will find out why later. For now this is working :)

Comment: Put this as a comment to an answer rather as an answer itself.